# ReactiveCocoa: rac_keywordify macros. For what purpose rac_keywordify is actually need?

Tags: macros, reactive-cocoa

In ReactiveCocoa there are two macros which are using in conjunction.

```
#define weakify(...) \
    rac_keywordify \
    metamacro_foreach_cxt(rac_weakify_,, __weak, __VA_ARGS__)

#define strongify(...) \
    rac_keywordify \
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wshadow\"") \
    metamacro_foreach(rac_strongify_,, __VA_ARGS__) \
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")

    #if DEBUG
    #define rac_keywordify autoreleasepool {}
    #else
    #define rac_keywordify try {} @catch (...) {}
    #endif
```

Could any one explain for what purpose actually need `rac_keywordify`?
I read the description about `rac_keywordify` but still don't understand.
And I will be much obliged if someone provide examples and description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `rac_keywordify` does is allow the use of the `@` symbol as a required prefix in front of the `weakify` and `strongify` macros. The `@` is not necessary, it's a style choice to make those macros look like keywords, like other language keywords, like `@try` or `@synchronize`.